# Can From trait implementations be lossy?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

### Context

I have a pair of related structs in my program, `Rom` and `ProfiledRom`. They both store a list of `u8` values and implement a common trait, `GetRom`, to provide access to those values.

```
trait GetRom {
    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> u8;
}
```

The difference is that `Rom` just wraps a simple `Vec<u8>`, but `ProfiledRom` wraps each byte in a `ProfiledByte` type that counts the number of times it is returned by `get`.

```
struct Rom(Vec<u8>);

struct ProfiledRom(Vec<ProfiledByte>);
struct ProfiledByte {
    value: u8;
    get_count: u32;
};
```

Much of my program operates on `trait GetRom` values, so I can substitute in `Rom` or `ProfiledRom` type/value depending on whether I want profiling to occur.

### Question

I have implemented `From<Rom> for ProfiledRom`, because converting a `Rom` to a `ProfiledRom` just involves wrapping each byte in a new `ProfiledByte`: a simple and lossless operation.

However, I'm not sure whether it's appropriate to implement `From<ProfiledRom> for Rom`, because `ProfiledRom` contains information (the get counts) that can't be represented in a `Rom`. If you did a round-trip conversion, these values would be lost/reset.

Is it appropriate to implement the `From` trait when only parts of the source object will be used?

### Related

I have seen that the standard library doesn't implement integer conversions like `From<i64> for i32` because these could result in bytes being truncated/lost. However, that seems like a somewhat distinct case from what we have here.

With the potentially-truncating integer conversion, you would need to inspect the original `i64` to know whether it would be converted appropriately. If you didn't, the behaviour or your code could change unexpectedly when you get an out-of-bounds value. However, in our case above, it's always statically clear what data is being preserved and what data is being lost. The conversion's behaviour won't suddenly change. It should be safer, but is it an appropriate use of the `From` trait?

Comment: The standard provide `TryFrom` when data could not be ok to convert, i64 => i8 for exemple. For me your problem is different, your main data is not lost. Standard also have some implementation of From who "lost" some information. `impl From<File> for Stdio` for exemple, So I think, it's ok if it makes sense.

Comment: Given that the two types share a trait, it sounds like you don't really need to convert between them. You can just rely on the trait as a generic bound and worry about the concrete type at construction or certain entry points. If you're worried that implementing `From` here might a foot gun, then perhaps don't do it until you actually need it.

Comment: [This was discussed in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/conversation/is-it-acceptable-for-a-from-trait-implementation-to-be-lossy).

Comment: [RFC: `FromLossy` and `TryFromLossy` traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2484)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`From` implementations are usually lossless, but there is currently no strict requirement that they be.

The ongoing discussion at [rust-lang/rfcs#2484](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2484) is related. Some possibilities include adding a `FromLossy` trait and more exactly prescribing the behaviour of `From`. We'll have to see where that goes.

For consideration, here are some `Target::from(Source)` implementations in the standard library:

## Lossless conversions

*Each `Source` value is converted into a distinct `Target` value.*

- [`u16::from(u8)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#impl-From<u8%3E), [`i16::from(u8)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i16.html#impl-From%3Cu8%3E) and other conversions to strictly-larger integer types.
- [`Vec<u8>::from(String)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From%3CString%3E)
- [`Vec<T>::from(BinaryHeap<T>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From<BinaryHeap<T%3E%3E)
- [`OsString::from(String)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#impl-From<String%3E)
- [`char::from(u8)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#impl-From<u8%3E)

## Lossy conversions

*Multiple `Source` values may be convert into the same `Target` value.*

- [`BinaryHeap<T>::from(Vec<T>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html#impl-From<Vec<T%3E%3E) loses the order of elements.
- [`Box<[T]>::from(Vec<T>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From<Vec<T>>-2) and [`Box<str>::from(String)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From<String%3E) lose any excess capacity.
- [`Vec<T>::from(VecDeque<T>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.Vec.html#impl-From<VecDeque<T%3E%3E) loses the internal split of elements exposed by [`.as_slices()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/vec_deque/struct.VecDeque.html#method.as_slices).

Comment: Did I miss any important examples? Comments or edits welcome.

Comment: `From<String>` for `Box<str>` loses the (possibly extra) capacity.

Comment: @trentcl Fair edit --- it did look quite weird. Thanks for the example, that's a funny case to think about; I'll add it.

Comment: Poking at it, I'm not 100% sure whether the capacity is actually lost. I need to test and see whether it's actually preserved on a round-trip.

Comment: I went digging. The capacity is lost in `Vec::into_boxed_slice`, [where it calls `shrink_to_fit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#640-647). This is necessary so that the `Box` can be safely dropped, but it means when you reconstitute the `String` its capacity and length will always be the same.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for looking into that. I guess [this applies for the capacity of any `From<Vec<T>> for Box<[T]>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f8f770943c33dc6bbe0e821385a2e7a6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).